# Javascript: Detect Carets Parent Node

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, parent, caret

I'm building a simple WYSIWYG editor inside an iframe with designMode on , currently I can make the selected text bold, italic and underline and to link, and they work fine.

But I would like to know when the **`caret`** is inside the **`b`**, **`i`**, **`u`**, **`a`**,  tags, so I can notify the user that the current selection is bold or whatever.

Examples:

`Hello <b>Stackover|flow</b> is cool!` = You are Inside the **`b`** tag

`<i>Be|st place</i>!` = You are Inside the **`i`** tag

`Hello <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Go|od stuff!</a>` = You are Inside the **`a`** tag

*No libraries please I would like to learn this stuff :)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

Comment: @Tyler Holien , I'm not talking about the caret position as a number, I would like to get it's Parent Node Name too, and the accepted answers solution works only on textareas.

Comment: True, sorry. Where is the caret, if not a textarea?

Comment: Nope :), I just edited my questions first line: I'm building a simple WYSIWYG editor inside an iframe with designMode on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MSIE lte 8: [TextRange.parentElement()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536654(v=vs.85).aspx)

Others: [DOMRange.commonAncestorContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.commonAncestorContainer)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function fx()
{

  var target=null;
  if(window.getSelection)
  {
    target=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
    return((target.nodeType===1)?target:target.parentNode);
  }
  else if(document.selection)
  {
    var target=document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
  }
  return target;
}
//-->
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(fx().tagName)" value="click">
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
Hello <b>Stackoverflow</b> is cool! <i>Best place</i>
Hello <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Good stuff!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Dr.Molle , I know about `commonAncestorContainer` , but +1 for `parentElement` :), My problem with `commonAncestorContainer.nodeName` is that gives me `#text` for every kind of text, sooo how should I get the real parent node name from it? :)

Comment: Choose `commonAncestorContainer.parentNode` if `commonAncestorContainer.nodeType` is not 1

Comment: Hmm I get `#text` with Chrome(9.0.597.84), Safari(5.0.3) , and nothing with firefox and opera, IE untested :|

Comment: OMG!!! This works on Chrome and Safari, cooool!!, I'm trying to make it since a weeek. But doesn't works on Firefox and Opera yet but maybe I missed something :)

Comment: Hmm there is a problem with iframe.contentWindow.onkeyup in firefox and opera, but this is another question, in the parent window works cool in all browsers here, so thanks very very much, you made me really happy!!

Comment: +1, since this will work in the vast majority of cases. There are a couple of cases that this won't work for: first, in IE, a selection can contain a `ControlRange` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than a `TextRange`, in which case `parentElement()` will cause an error. You can filter this case out: `else if(document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control")`. Second, if there's no selection or caret, `getRangeAt(0)` could throw an error, but that won't happen so long as the editable element has the focus.

Comment: Tim, you're right, it will make problems if there is a controlRange inside the selection. But the requested thing is the caret, you can simply collapse() the range, and nothing will be inside :)