# How can I select an object based on cursor position?

Tags: javascript, cursor, range, selection, dom-traversal

**I want to attach a class to an object based on cursor position.**

I understand the basics of `range`, and can get/manipulate selected text, but I'm at a loss as to how I can use the cursor to attach a class to the object it's currently in.

I've through about maybe adding a temporary element at the cursor then traversing to the parent element and attaching the class before removing the temporary element. That really seems messy though, and I would have to assign something to initialize it (keyboard shortcut or on `keydown`).

Any ideas? I've search around but haven't found anything like what I'm wanting.

Comment: you could try to get the parentNode of the character where the cursor is at, should be the wrapped element and youre looking for its class

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @johnSmith That got me on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: @AshleyMedway yes yes, but I wanted to know if it was even possible, and what methods I might use to obtain it. If I had a better idea (which I now do, thanks to John), obviously I would have posted some code. Solution to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to John's lead and results from a more appropriate search term, I found this:

[Javascript: Detect Carets Parent Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913940/javascript-detect-carets-parent-node)

To answer the question, here's how it's done.

```
function getCursorParentNode()
{

  var target = null;
  if(window.getSelection)
  {
    target = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
    return((target.nodeType===1) ? target : target.parentNode);
  }
  else if(document.selection)
  {
    var target = document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
  }
  return target;

}
```

Then, initialize it however you prefer, for example:

```
$('.content').on('keydown',function(){

  var target = getCursorParentNode();
  target.className = 'red';

});
```

**[Here's a fiddle to demonstrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/539Ye/)**

Comment: Just to note, the above method will replace any existing classes the object has assigned to it, so I ended up wrapping `target` as a jQuery object and using `addClass`